# почему при добавлении анимации элемент резко перемещается в совсем другое место

Tags: html, css, запрос

при добавлении анимации, h1 уходит в другое место, хотя в стайлах ничего такого нет. в чем причина?

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate bounce');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('h1').removeClass('activate bounce');
  }, 1000);

})
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

.activate {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 7em;
      margin: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: arial;
      text-align: center;">lorem</h1>
      
<button>bounce</button>
```

анимация взята с [сайта](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что, `transform` может быть в единственно экземпляре, иначе будут перезаписываться

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').addClass('activate bounce');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('h1').removeClass('activate bounce');
  }, 1000);

})
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.activate {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 7em;
      margin: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: arial;
      text-align: center;">lorem</h1>
      
<button>bounce</button>
```